# Apple-ios-samples - RosyWriter - MovieRecorder Where are video files recorded?

Tags: ios, video, directory, video-recording

I am trying to access a video file recorded by MovieRecorder in RosyWriter (Apple-ios-samples). Temporary directory NSDocumentDirectory is used with a path like:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A8ECC1B-F4D5-413E-B624-440262A82B7F/tmp
but I cannot access it programmatically although it is visible in Gallery. I do not find it in the tmp directory.
Any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved !
After recording the file was removed by:

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:_recordingURL error:NULL]